# how to prevent user from dragging google map to gray area

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using Google maps API to show country.

If I move the map up or down it is possible to get to gray area. ( not matter to the size of the zoom )

Is it possible to prevent the option to get to the gray area meaning to control on the move of the user and when the gray area should appear to prevent from him to do the move of the map to this area ?

Comment: Do you want to stop any of the grey area being seen at all? That is possible but complicated (I'll work it out and post it here unless someone else gets there first). Otherwise a search for "Google Maps constrain dragging" will find some relevant questions and answers about limiting where the map centre can be dragged to (which won't necessarily stop grey areas being *seen*).

Comment: yes I want to stop any of the gray area being seen at all , when do you post the solution out ?

Comment: How long it takes depends on the day job!

Comment: Thanks for the help when you will post it how I can find it ?

Comment: You can star this question, but you will get a notification similar to a comment in your inbox.

Comment: I am sorry but I am new in the stackoverflow what do you mean star the question ? how does it will help me to find the post ?